# Excel debugging VBA "Run-time error '424': Object required"

Tags: vba, excel

Using Macros to create a pivot table with the click of a button. I download new reports every day so it's a different Excel worksheet and sheet name each time.

I've managed to get around the fact that it's a different workbook name by simply renaming the relevant tab "data" each time. I've gotten it to create the pivot table I want, except it's giving me "Count" instead of "Sum" like I need. The error I get is

> Run-time error '424':
>   Object required

The highlighted line is `.Position = 1` near the end and I'm not sure what's broken here.

```
   Columns("A:A").Select
Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("A1"), DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=True, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, FieldInfo _
    :=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), _
    Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), Array(13, 1 _
    ), Array(14, 1), Array(15, 1))
Cells.Select
Sheets.Add
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
    "data!R1C1:R1048576C15", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable _
    TableDestination:="Sheet1!R3C1", TableName:="PivotTable2", DefaultVersion _
    :=xlPivotTableVersion14
Sheets("Sheet1").Select
Cells(3, 1).Select
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable2").PivotFields("Date"), "Count of Date", xlCount
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable2").PivotFields("Store Listing Visitors"), _
    "Count of Store Listing Visitors", xlCount
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
    "PivotTable2").PivotFields("Installers"), "Count of Installers", xlCount
With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Count of Date")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With
ExecuteExcel4Macro _
    "PIVOT.FIELD.PROPERTIES(""PivotTable2"",""Count of Store Listing Visitors"",,,2)"
ExecuteExcel4Macro _
    "PIVOT.FIELD.PROPERTIES(""PivotTable2"",""Count of Installers"",,,2)"
```

I appreciate your help in advance!

Comment: Please post code only as text formatted as code block (at least 4 spaces indented). Code in images is hard for other users to copy and fix.

Comment: @Peh - hard is a bit of an understatement!  Takes ages to write the OCR code needed to read the image.  I don't think I know any coders that will take the 15 minutes needed to type the code in when they can spend weeks writing the OCR code instead. :)

Comment: I added the code, do you see it now?

Comment: could you try it without the "with"? so address the Pivot two times

Comment: @RealCheeseLord which "with" should I remove?

Comment: `With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Count of Date")
    .Orientation = xlRowField
    .Position = 1
End With`

Comment: To `ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Count of Date").Orientation = xlRowField
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Count of Date").Position = 1
`

Comment: I got an error message: "Run-time error '1004': Unable to get the PivotTables property of the Worksheet class

Comment: please stop providing partial information ... which line gives you the error 1004 ?

Answer (score 0):

here is a rewrite of your code

i think that you would have an easier time debugging, if you formatted your code in a more legible way.

```
Sub pivTest()

    Columns("A:A").TextToColumns _
        Destination:=Range("A1"), _
        DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, _
        ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, _
        Tab:=True, _
        Semicolon:=False, _
        Comma:=True, _
        Space:=False, _
        Other:=False, _
        FieldInfo:=Array(Array(1, 1), Array(2, 1), Array(3, 1), Array(4, 1), _
                         Array(5, 1), Array(6, 1), Array(7, 1), Array(8, 1), _
                         Array(9, 1), Array(10, 1), Array(11, 1), Array(12, 1), _
                         Array(13, 1), Array(14, 1), Array(15, 1))

'   Cells.Select  ' do not use

    Sheets.Add    ' what is the name of this sheet ?

    ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create( _
            SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
            SourceData:="data!R1C1:R1048576C15", _
            Version:=xlPivotTableVersion14).CreatePivotTable _
                                                    TableDestination:="Sheet2!R3C1", _
                                                    TableName:="PivotTable2", _
                                                    DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion14
'   Sheets("Sheet1").Select   ' do not use

'   Cells(3, 1).Select        ' do not use

    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Set pt = Sheets("Sheet1").PivotTables("PivotTable2")

    pt.AddDataField pt.PivotFields("Date"), "Count of Date", xlCount
    pt.AddDataField pt.PivotFields("Store Listing Visitors"), "Count of Store Listing Visitors", xlCount
    pt.AddDataField pt.PivotFields("Installers"), "Count of Installers", xlCount

    pt.PivotFields("Count of Date").Orientation = xlRowField
    pt.PivotFields("Date").Position = 1           ' it is not "Count of Date" anymore, because previous line moved it out of the "Sum Values"

    ExecuteExcel4Macro "PIVOT.FIELD.PROPERTIES(""PivotTable2"",""Count of Store Listing Visitors"",,,2)"
    ExecuteExcel4Macro "PIVOT.FIELD.PROPERTIES(""PivotTable2"",""Count of Installers"",,,2)"

End Sub
```